# Why has DocuSign EventNotification stopped working?

Tags: php, docusignapi

In 2017 I integrated DocuSign with a website using the Official DocuSign PHP Client (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client).

I took the example code and modified it so that it registered an EventNotification which would call back to the website once the signing process is complete. Code below.

```
        require_once('docusign-php-client/autoload.php');

        $username = "XXXXX";
        $password = "XXXXX";
        $integrator_key = "XXXXX";

        // change to production (www.docusign.net) before going live
        $host = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi";

        // create configuration object and configure custom auth header
        $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost($host);
        $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");

        // instantiate a new docusign api client
        $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        $accountId = null;

        try {
            //*** STEP 1 - Login API: get first Account ID and baseURL
            $authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
            $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
            $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
            if (isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0) {
                $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
                $host = $loginAccount->getBaseUrl();
                $host = explode("/v2", $host);
                $host = $host[0];

                // UPDATE configuration object
                $config->setHost($host);

                // instantiate a NEW docusign api client (that has the correct baseUrl/host)
                $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);

                if (isset($loginInformation)) {
                    $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();
                    if (!empty($accountId)) {
                        //*** STEP 2 - Signature Request from a Template
                        // create envelope call is available in the EnvelopesApi
                        $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

                        // assign recipient to template role by setting name, email, and role name.  Note that the
                        // template role name must match the placeholder role name saved in your account template.
                        $templateRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
                        $templateRole->setEmail($vars['client_email']['value']);
                        //$templateRole->setEmail("robbielewis@me.com");
                        $templateRole->setName($vars['client_name']['value']);
                        $templateRole->setRoleName("Signee");

                        // pre-populate text tabs
                        $tabFields = array();

                        foreach ($vars as $var) {
                            $tabField = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
                            $tabField->setTabLabel($var['label']);
                            $tabField->setValue($var['value']);
                            $tabFields[] = $tabField;
                        }

                        $tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
                        $tabs->setTextTabs($tabFields);
                        $templateRole->setTabs($tabs);

                        // create event notification webhook
                        $envelope_events = [
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("delivered"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("completed"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("declined"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("voided"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent")
                        ];

                        $recipient_events = [
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Sent"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Delivered"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Completed"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Declined"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("AuthenticationFailed"),
                            (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("AutoResponded")
                        ];

                        $event_notification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EventNotification();
                        $event_notification->setUrl("https://www.XXXXX.com/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX/XXXXX.php?action=docusign-callback");
                        $event_notification->setLoggingEnabled("true");
                        $event_notification->setRequireAcknowledgment("true");
                        $event_notification->setUseSoapInterface("false");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateWithSoap("false");
                        $event_notification->setSignMessageWithX509Cert("false");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeDocuments("true");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeEnvelopeVoidReason("true");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeTimeZone("true");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField("true");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeDocumentFields("true");
                        $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateOfCompletion("true");
                        $event_notification->setEnvelopeEvents($envelope_events);
                        $event_notification->setRecipientEvents($recipient_events);

                        // instantiate a new envelope object and configure settings
                        $envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
                        $envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Please review and sign your booking contract");
                        $envelop_definition->setTemplateId("XXXXX");
                        $envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles(array($templateRole));
                        $envelop_definition->setEventNotification($event_notification);

                        // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
                        $envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");

                        // optional envelope parameters
                        $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
                        $options->setCdseMode(null);
                        $options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);

                        // create and send the envelope (aka signature request)
                        $envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, $options);
                        if (!empty($envelop_summary)) {
                            echo "Contract sent at " . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') .' to '.$templateRole->getEmail();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $ex) {
            echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
            file_put_contents('XXXXX.log', "\n\n" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . ' - Docusign API error ' . $ex->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
            wp_mail('XXXXX', 'Docusign API error', date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . ' - Docusign API error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }
```

This worked fine for a couple of years until recently we stopped getting the EventNotification request to our server from Docusign when the envelope is signed. The envelope is still created successfully and sent to the recipient.

Things I have tried to resolve the issue:

- Created many test envelopes using my script and signed them
- Monitored the access logs on the server for any http requests following the signing of an envelope that was created by the script, nothing received
- Updated the DocuSign PHP Client to the latest version
- Enabled logging in DocuSign and checked that the EventNotification request is being received by DocuSign when the envelope is created, see here: https://pastebin.com/xbS338Hx
- Contacted my host to ensure that there is no hardware firewall that could be preventing the server receiving HTTP requests from DocuSign
- Turned off Cloudflare DNS proxy to make sure that it isn't blocking the request to the server
- Contacted DocuSign Support who said to post here as they cannot provide assistance with code issues.

What else can I try to pinpoint the cause of this issue?

Comment: can you check connect logs from DocuSign admin to see if you see any errors?

Comment: also, can you confirm TLS version on your server? (just in case, it's most likely 1.1 and above)

Comment: @InbarGazit https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test says the domain is running on TLS 1.3

Comment: @InbarGazit Found Connect Failures. This is the message "https://www.XXXXX.com/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX/XXXXX.php?action=docusign-callback :: Error - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.; Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: did you recently upgrade to TLS 1.3? was it working when you used TLS 1.2? just wondering if that's related

Comment: the error above typically means something on your server is not working property to accept the message from DocuSign.
I would suggest to see when was the last time it did work and what changed when it stopped

Comment: potentially some configuration on your server or something else like a service is not running or has the wrong credentials etc.

Comment: @InbarGazit it was a security plugin for Wordpress blocking the request *facepalm* - I have posted the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you did this. Noticed you have setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent") three times, which likely isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DocuSign Connect Failures screen in DocuSign Admin I was able to see failed connections in the list.

```
https://www.XXXXX.com/wp-content/plugins/sXXXXX/XXXXX.php?action=docusign-callback :: Error - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

It turned out to be iThemes Security Plugin for Wordpress denying the requests. I disabled the plugin and republished the most recent failed request in DocuSign Admin. The request came through successfully.

Comment: Happy to help!!